# REST API + AngularJS (Can't see cookies)

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I'm having issues trying to pass a cookie from a REST method to the browser (client), I have searched this issue a lot and I hasn't found a solution yet, hope you can help.

I'm following the [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) documentation and other Stack Overflow posts.

What I have is a dummy REST public login method as follow:

> ```
> @RequestMapping(path = "/login/{login}/{password}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
> public
> @ResponseBody
> User login(
>         @PathVariable(name = "login") String login,
>         @PathVariable(name = "password") String password,
>         HttpServletRequest request,
>         HttpServletResponse response) {
>
>     logger.debug(String.format("query: /public/login/%s/%s", login, password));
>     User user = userDAO.findByLogin(login);
>
>     try {
>         if (user != null && user.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password)) {
>
>             response.addCookie(new Cookie("me.public.key", configuration.getSecurity().getPublicAccessKey()));
>             response.addCookie(new Cookie("me.public.key2", configuration.getSecurity().getPublicAccessKey()));
>             response.addCookie(new Cookie("me.public.key3", configuration.getSecurity().getPublicAccessKey()));
>
>             user.setLastSeen(new Date());
>             logger.info("[" + login + "] access granted");
>             return userDAO.save(user);
>         } else {
>             logger.warn("[" + login + "] access denied");
>         }
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         logger.error("[" + login + "] got error validating login", e);
>     }
>
>     return new User("N/A", "N/A");
>
> }
> ```

If I call it using curl from a terminal I get all my cookies:

curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8090/public/login/service/2761491648E0FF90FA8F20EE3DB18C5AD0614CF615814D4E52DC31E70F5CBDEB8F5AEAA1A798367DEC4C399167B96A83755A59D082FD6F353B166E6A5345275' -c -; echo -e ''

...

> HttpOnly_localhost    FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  B9D9C893F0582F550AC963908DA3D274 
>   localhost FALSE   /public/login/service/  FALSE   0   me.public.key   thegloriousPUBLICkey
>
> localhost FALSE   /public/login/service/  FALSE   0   me.public.key2  thegloriousPUBLICkey
>
> localhost FALSE   /public/login/service/  FALSE   0   me.public.key3  thegloriousPUBLICkey

This way I'm sure that the cookies are there, however, when I try to get those from the client (AngularJS 1.6.5) I got nothing! very frustrating, I have tried a lot of stuff so far.

My page **body** is:

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="public">

...

 <div class="centered" style="margin-top: 80px;" ng-controller="login">

            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="username" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><input type="button" ng-click="submit()" value="Sign in" ng-disabled="password == null" /></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
```

And my **angular module** is:

```js
var publicModule = angular.module('public', ['ngCookies']);

publicModule.controller('login', function($scope, $http, $cookies) {

    $scope.username = null;
    $scope.password = null;
    $scope.submit = function() {

        $http.get('/public/login/' + $scope.username + '/' + $scope.password, {withCredentials: true}).
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.response = response.data;

            if ($scope.username == response.data.login) {

                var tmp = response.headers();
                for (var key in tmp) {
                  console.log(key + " => " + tmp[key]);
                }

                console.log("1: " + $cookies.get('me.public.key'));

                angular.forEach($cookies.getAll(), function(v, k) {
                    console.log("v: " + v + " k: " + k);
                });

                alert("Access Granted");
            } else {
                alert("Access Denied");
            }

        });
    }

});
```

And every time $cookies.get('me.public.key') is undefined!

[image: Chrome console]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is REST on a different port than page is? What exactly are you trying to do with the cookies? Note that you can't access httpOnly cookies using javascript for security reasons

Comment: All is on the same port, is the same service so far. Yes I know about httpOnly, remember that by default is declared "false". I just want to pass some information to ten other side, nothing fancy

Comment: I gave up and move the project to Angular v4